# Cronbach's alpha and reverse-scored items

Tags: cronbachs-alpha

When calculating Cronbach's $\alpha$, would I include the reverse scores? I have 20 items in total, including 11 reverse-scored items. Would I just calculate the original scores?

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse the scores of the reversed items before computing Cronbach's $\alpha$.

If you wish to reverse items into the original scale you can compute:
$$
r_{jk} = (max_j-min_j) - x_{jk}
$$

Where $max_j$ and $min_j$ are the theoretical maximum and minimum values of item $j$, $x_{jk}$ is the score of individual $k$ in item $j$ and $r_{jk}$ is the reversed score of individual $k$ in item $k$.